# TableView not scrolling in iOS11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios11

I am using the text fields inside the table view. On keyboard next button, the focus get shift to the next text field, this working fine still the iOS 10. but on iOS 11 table is not getting scrolled. Following scroll help me to scroll the table view.

Below method to scroll tableview up on which text field is selected, write this code in textfield delegate method.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
     // calculate the nsindexpath based on the textfield which is selected
       tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: textField.tag + 1, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Does textField.tag have the same value as your row ? (print while running to be sure)